# If I scan a sector to 100% can a future mission decrease that number?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In order to avoid missing any side quests I put my priority missions on hold and I'm off playing galactic go-fer.

I know that I may not be able to get to 100% if certain conditions aren't met, but once I get a sector to read 100% explored is there any chance that a mission or plot line can open up and bump it back down?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, missions can't change a sector's assets recovered %, but they can reduce it for the entire star system, if additional sectors are unlocked.

Comment: Good to know and makes good sense.  Glad they don't add new missions to otherwise completed sectors.

Comment: I believe missions do pop up in sectors that may have been explored, but they do not affect the Assets Recovered percentage.